# How to solve this error in R: water.exceptions.H2OConcurrentModificationException: Rollups not possible, because Vec was deleted?

Tags: r, machine-learning, h2o, h2o.ai

For my first use of Package H2o on Rstudio, I received the following message for Ridge model

```
Error: water.exceptions.H2OConcurrentModificationException: Rollups not possible, because Vec was deleted
```

Here is the code I used and unfortunately I can't share my database because it is confidential

```
library(h2o)
h2o.init(nthreads = -1) 
h2o.no_progress()                    
learn.h2o<-as.h2o(learn_preppeds)   
test.h2o<-as.h2o(test_preppeds)
Lambda<- 10^seq(-3, 3, length = 100)
x <- setdiff(colnames(learn.h2o), c("NBCLAIM", "Offset")) 
y <- "NBCLAIM"      # Target variable
offset <- "Offset"  # log(exposure)
glm_fit_ridge<-h2o.glm(  
x = x,   
y = y,                                            
offset_column = offset,  
training_frame = learn.h2o,  
validation_frame = test.h2o,  
family = "poisson",  
link = 'log',
nfolds= 10, # 10 fold cross-validation  
alpha = 0,  
lambda =Lambda,  
interactions= interactions_list, 
keep_cross_validation_predictions = TRUE,  
seed = 2    # For reproducibility)
```

Answer (score 0):

Most likely a bug in **h2o**. Yesterday, there was a new fix release so if you can, I'd suggest upgrading to the newest version. Note that not all versions end up on `CRAN` (**h2o** releases more frequently than recommended on **CRAN**) so you can install the new version from [here](https://h2o-release.s3.amazonaws.com/h2o/rel-zipf/4/index.html).

If that doesn't help, you can file a bug report as described [here](https://github.com/h2oai/h2o-3/blob/master/CONTRIBUTING.md).

There might also be a chance that you could mitigate the issue by changing the [solver](https://docs.h2o.ai/h2o/latest-stable/h2o-docs/data-science/algo-params/solver.html) but in this case, it would still be nice if you'd file a bug report (so it gets fixed). Ideally with more details, e.g., stack trace from the Java backend (might be printed in the error message in `RStudio` and definitely is in the logs).

Comment: Hello,
I tried your suggestion to download h2o from the link you gave me
'''
'''
 but I got this error

Comment: package or namespace load failed for ‘h2o’ in get(method, envir = home):
 lazy-load database 'C:/Users/Documents/R/win-library/4.0/h2o/R/h2o.rdb' is corrupt
De plus : Warning messages:
1: In .registerS3method(fin[i, 1], fin[i, 2], fin[i, 3], fin[i, 4],  :
  redémarrage de l'évaluation d'une promesse interrompue
2: In get(method, envir = home) :
  redémarrage de l'évaluation d'une promesse interrompue
3: In get(method, envir = home) : internal error -5 in R_decompress1

Comment: It looks to me like there is a problem during the installation. I'd suggest to restart the R session and try again. Also it is possible that h2o is loaded on load for whatever reason so it might be worth trying to "Session -> Clear workspace..." before the installation. If it still doesn't work try installing it in vanilla R session (run in CMD `R --vanilla`), that should ensure that nothing gets preloaded before the installation which seems to me was the cause.